# Associate Rails active model with two different models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

Is there a way to use inheritance with Ruby on Rails Active Model?

I have two models to which I want to add comments. It would be cool if I can just use one Comment model that could be associated with both models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [Polymorphic Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations)

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end

class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Image < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end
```